# Fixed pod count per node

Tags: kubernetes

I need fixed pod count on each node and count should stay fixed in any case. Pod count will be different on each node. Should I create separate deployments for each node or somehow use taints?

Comment: Yes, you can use taints and toleration but keep in mind that you will loose some benefits of using k8s in this case. Specially, you will be introducing single point of failure in your system for example, no pod of type A will be running if its node type is down.

Comment: Could you provide an example how can I specify particular deployment pod count per node?

Comment: You could achieve this aim by combining [affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity)

Comment: How to deal with the replica counts per node using affinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are done with defining taints on required node. Only pods that have tolerations for them will be deployed on that particular node. Now, its fairly easy to control the number of pods that you want to run for that deployment.

deployment can be scaled up and down using

```
kubectl scale deployment <my_deployment> --replicas=<number of desired pods>
```

So, effectively you will be controlling number of pods on particular node.

***Note***: As I already commented, this design will be introducing single point of failure in your system for example, no pod of type A will be running if its node type is down.

Comment: Let's say I have a deployment of 3 replicas and cluster of 2 nodes. How to taint that node A would run 1 and node B would run 2?

Comment: You can try preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution with weight field as described at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/ or create two deployments and manage them via single service. In case you are using openshift, refer https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#admin-guide-max-pods-per-node

Comment: Probably I will go for separate deployments as other options inadequate complicates things.